# Split mysql row into multiple rows based on a date in the cake php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have data in table like below-

[image]

But i want to Split mysql row into multiple rows based on a date

[image]

Because i want to count number of send email between two dates like below code -

```
$condition[] = array(
                'LeadTime.send ' => 1
                'DATE(LeadTime.date) >= ' =>   $this->request->data['from_date'],
                'DATE(LeadTime.date) <= ' =>   $this->request->data['end_date'],
                );
}
$count = $this->Time->find('count', array(
                             'conditions' => $condition,
                              ));
pr($count);
```

I m not getting first should i UNION table data base on date column or direct i can implement it in cake php.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL statement that would count the results based on your table design.

```
SELECT  SUM(IF(first_send = 1 
                 AND first_start_date BETWEEN from_date AND end_date
                 AND second_send = 1 
                 AND second_start_date BETWEEN from_date AND end_date
             ,2,1)) as amount
FROM times
WHERE 
  (first_send = 1 AND first_start_date BETWEEN from_date AND end_date)
  OR 
  (second_send = 1 AND second_start_date BETWEEN from_date AND end_date);
```

**Implementing within Cakephp**: You probably should use a [prepared statement](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements) since stopping sql injection when creating the column is going to be difficult.

```
$db = $this->Time->getDataSource();
$db->fetchAll(
    'SELECT  SUM(IF(first_send = 1 
                 AND first_start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
                 AND second_send = 1 
                 AND second_start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
             ,2,1)) as amount
     FROM times
     WHERE 
      (first_send = 1 AND first_start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)
       OR 
      (second_send = 1 AND second_start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)',
  array($this->request->data['from_date'],$this->request->data['end_date']
       ,$this->request->data['from_date'],$this->request->data['end_date']
       ,$this->request->data['from_date'],$this->request->data['end_date']
       ,$this->request->data['from_date'],$this->request->data['end_date']));
```

---

The difficulty/ problem with using `find` is preventing a sql injection, as seen in the code below.

```
$this->Time->virtualFields['amount'] = 'SUM(IF(first_send = 1 
                 AND first_start_date BETWEEN' . $this->request->data['from_date'] . ' AND ' . $this->request->data['end_date']
                 . ' AND second_send = 1 '
                 . ' AND second_start_date BETWEEN ' . $this->request->data['from_date'] . ' AND ' . $this->request->data['end_date']
                 . ',2,1))';

$conditions = array('OR' =>(
    array('AND'=>array('Time.first_send' => '1'
                      ,'Time.first_start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => 
                          array($this->request->data['from_date']
                               ,$this->request->data['end_date']))),
    array('AND'=>array('Time.second_send' => '1'
                      ,'Time.second_start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?' => 
                          array($this->request->data['from_date']
                               ,$this->request->data['end_date'])))
  ));

$this->Time->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'fields' => array('amount'),
    ));
```